# Is the RAT pump on the A320 standard fitment or is it an "option"?

Tags: boeing-737, airbus-a320, rat

Is the RAT pump standard or optional on the A320 aircraft?
What about the B737?

Comment: What RAT "pump"? The RAT is an electrical generator, not a pump, are you asking about a supplemental hydraulic system? Or the Ram Air Turbine generator?

Comment: Depending on the system or a/c RATs drive both an AC generator and a hydraulic pump.

Answer (score 4):

A RAT is never an optional piece of equipment. It is only there because the design of the aircraft systems require it in order for the aircraft to meet airworthiness certification.

Answer (score 2):

The B-737 does not have a RAT.

Comment: I can find examples of dual-engine failure in a 737 (e.g. TACA 110) which is a fairly desperate situation, but none where both engines *and* the APU have failed in a 737 (e.g. due to fuel shortage as per Gimli 767) - I guess that would mostly be fatal in a 737.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick    It would be a really bad day, but you'd have the battery for electrical systems, and hydraulics from the engines windmilling, and manual reversion on the flight controls (no fly-by-wire). So not necessarily unsurvivable. But ***any time*** you lose both motors, things are pretty bad!

Comment: Due to a faulty battery Garuda 421 had also the APU down.